# Fetch data from Firestore using Provider

Tags: flutter, provider

I would like to fetch data from a Firestore Doc and display anywhere in the app. For example, I would like to fetch objectID from my Firestore database, which looks like this.

[image]

I want to display this string on the UI by doing something like this

```
Widget _displayObjectID() {
final provider = ShortlistProvider.of(context);
String objectID = provider.objectID;
  return Text(objectID);
}
```

I want to easily access this anywhere in my app. Is it possible? If so, please tell me what the approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access data from all screens in the application, you can use [MultiProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/MultiProvider-class.html).

```
void main(){
   runApp(
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: ((context) => SampleProvider.instance)),
        ],
        child: const MyApp(),
      ),
   );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
       initialRoute: /home
    );
  }
}
```

SampleProvider should look like this:

```
class SampleProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
   String? _objectId;
   String? get objectId => _objectId;
   
   SampleProvider.instance(){
     getObjectIdFromFirestore();
   }

   getObjectIdFromFirestore() async {
      //The code used to fetch the object id from the "Firestore".
      _objectId = 'JvadsfAJdfavdAJAdf';
      notifyListeners();
   }
}
```

Now you can access the "objectId" from all screens and listen for changes.

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeView({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       appBar: ...
       body: Column(
         children: [
           Text(context.read<SampleProvider>().objectId ?? ''),
           //You can use "Selector" widget to listen for changes in "objectId".
           Selector<SampleProvider, String?>(
              selector: (_, provider) => provider.objectId,
              builder: (_, value, __) => Text(value ?? ''),
           ),
         ], 
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

To access the "SampleProvider" class in child widgets:

```
SampleProvider provider = context.read<SampleProvider>();
```

or

```
SampleProvider provider = Provider.of<SampleProvider>(context, listen: false);
```

The example above contains only one alternative.
There are many other options in the [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package to access classes or listen for changes.

These options are described in detail in the documentation.
You can choose the most suitable method for your scenario by reviewing the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/provider-library.html).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.. it helps me understand better.. but I am lost at  getObjectIdFromFirestore() async {
      //The code used to fetch the object id from the "Firestore".
      _objectId = 'JvadsfAJdfavdAJAdf';
      notifyListeners();
   }

Would you mind telling me how to fetch Firestore data in this part of code?
Thank you